# Rails respond_to js on rails controller method

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails

I'm trying to run a js.erb file for when a worker has been updated, but nothing happens. as if it's not running the js.erb file

I have this in my controller:

```
def update
 @worker = Worker.find(params[:id])
 respond_to do |format|
   if @worker.update(worker_params)
     format.js
     format.html { redirect_to @worker }
   else
     format.html {render :edit }
   end
 end
end
```

and a corresponding file at:

/app/views/workers/update.js.erb

contents of that file is a publish helper from private_pub gem

```
<% publish_to "/messages/new" do %>
$("#present").load(location.href + " #present");
<% end %>
```

I don't get any errors or anything that I can see. can't quite figure out what I'm missing

UPDATE:

I added remote: true to the update form, now the js file is being executed as expected. but the issue now is that when I press submit, he runs the js file but stops after that, he is supoused to redirect the page back to the workers show again.

Comment: What you're missing is a description of what is or is not happening vs. what should or should not be happening.

Comment: It depends on a lot of things. If you could upload your complete application to github or somewhere else it would be great.

Comment: I don't think I can do that. but maybe some suggestions on how to trouble shoot these kinds of issues may be useful

Comment: @crazettett Start with posting log lines from log/development.log of your application, which are relevant to your #update request.